# Kubernetes Postgres Database Upgrade to HA

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

We have an API with multiple services, each with its own Postgres database. Initially, we made a mistake by using bitnami/postgresql with Kubernetes. However, we now need to scale up our Postgres replica, which requires us to switch to bitnami/postgresql-ha.
How can we make this switch with minimal downtime? Additionally, how can we migrate the data from the old database to the new one?

I researched Database Update Strategies and found that the recommended approach is to create a new database, migrate all data to it, keep the old one running, and then, once everything is working, migrate the data again and update the postgres URL to the new database. Is this correct?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/upgrading-postgresql-standalone-high-availability-cluster-amazon/ . The approach you found in your research is generally correct. It's a common practice to create a new database, migrate the data, test, and then switch the connections to the new database to minimize downtime and ensure a smooth transition

Comment: Which command would you use to copy the data from the standalone Postgres to HA?

Comment: `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` should do the trick there